# Configuration Redis Sentinel in Micronaut

Tags: docker, redis, micronaut, redis-sentinel

I currently have a running application with Redis and I would like to add Redis Sentinel configuration to ensure high availability for my database. Could someone help me with configuring Redis Sentinel in Micronaut?

Application.yml file:

```yaml
redis:
  uri: redis-sentinel://localhost:26379,localhost:26380,localhost:26381/0#redismaster
```

My main code file:

```java
public class MyRedisRepository {

    private final RedisClient client;

    @Inject
    public MyRedisRepository (RedisClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public void save(String message) {
        StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = client.connect();

        try {

            connection.sync().set("my-key", message);

            if (connection.sync().exec().wasDiscarded()) {
                log.error("While trying to save message Redis transaction has been discarded.");
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            log.error("Exception occurred while saving message. Transaction discarded: {}", connection.sync().discard(), exc);
        }
    }    
}
```

In Docker, I have running:

- 3 Sentinel nodes (172.21.0.4, 172.21.0.5, 172.21.0.7)
- 1 Redis Master node (172.21.0.2)
- 1 Redis Slave node 172.21.0.3)

Unfortunately, my application is not working as expected and is throwing an error:

```
Error starting Micronaut server: Unable to connect to 172.21.0.2:6379
```

where `172.21.0.2` is IP Redis Master Contatainer

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You say you are "having trouble" - what exactly is going wrong? (What is the current result?)

Comment: @ryanwebjackson 
If I understand correctly, my application is currently connecting directly to the Redis Master node in my Application.yml configuration, bypassing 3 Sentinel nodes. I don't know how to include the 3 Sentinel nodes in my application configuration.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson : I updated my post and now my application is  throwing a specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I managed to establish the connection only after migrating to Kubernetes and changing the library to Jedis (allowing the use of certificates).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).